# DFS function for finding islands in 2D array returning incorrect numbers

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a function that looks at a 2D array and returns "islands," clusters of any number that isn't 0 basically. Simplified, below I've declared graph that should return 5 - as there are 5 places where the 1s are grouped/solo and surrounded by zeros. Can anyone see what's wrong with this code?

```
    func numIslands(grid: [Array<Int>]) -> Int{
        if(grid == nil || grid.count == 0 || grid[0].count == 0){
            return 0
        }

        let m = grid.count
        let n = grid[0].count

        var count = 0
        for i in 0...m-1{
            for j in 0...n-1{
                if grid[i][j] >= 1 {
                    count += 1
                    merge(grid: grid, i: i, j: j);
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    func merge(grid: [Array<Int>], i: Int, j: Int){
        var grid = grid
        let m = grid.count
        let n = grid[0].count

        if(i < 0 || i >= m || j<0 || j >= n || grid[i][j] != 1){
            return
        }

        grid[i][j] = 0

        merge(grid: grid, i: i-1, j:j)
        merge(grid: grid, i: i+1, j:j)
        merge(grid: grid, i: i, j: j-1)
        merge(grid: grid, i: i, j: j+1)
    }
```

```
    var graph = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]


    print(numIslands(grid: graph))
    //returns 10, should be 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error is here:

```
func merge(grid: [Array<Int>], i: Int, j: Int) {
    var grid = grid // Make a mutable copy

    // ... modify `grid` ...
}
```

Arrays are *value types* in Swift. The `merge()` function modifies the local mutable variable `grid`, but not the passed argument. Therefore in the main loop

```
var count = 0
for i in 0...m-1{
    for j in 0...n-1{
        if grid[i][j] >= 1 {
            count += 1
            merge(grid: grid, i: i, j: j);
        }
    }
}
```

the grid is never modified, and the loop just counts the number of `>= 1` entries.

What you need is an “inout parameter”

```
func merge(grid: inout [Array<Int>], i: Int, j: Int){
    let m = grid.count
    let n = grid[0].count

    if(i < 0 || i >= m || j<0 || j >= n || grid[i][j] != 1){
        return
    }

    grid[i][j] = 0

    merge(grid: &grid, i: i-1, j:j)
    merge(grid: &grid, i: i+1, j:j)
    merge(grid: &grid, i: i, j: j-1)
    merge(grid: &grid, i: i, j: j+1)
}
```

and only the main function makes a copy and passes it to the function as an inout argument with `&`:

```
var grid = grid
// ...
merge(grid: &grid, i: i, j: j);
```

With that change, the result will be `6` (and not the expected `5`) because `merge()` does not merge *diagonal* neighbours. But that should now be easy to fix.